# Determining Domain Base Name from Nslookup Results

Tags: bash, shell-script, nslookup

I am trying to search all IP addresses that connected to my server and want to find abusive servers from `nslookup` results.

```
nslookup 31.204.150.10 | grep "in-addr"
```

Some example results:

```
209.190.54.154          154.54.190.209.in-addr.arpa name = 9a.36.be.static.xlhost.com.
209.51.199.34           34.199.51.209.in-addr.arpa  name = 22.c7.33.static.xlhost.com.
209.51.197.234          234.197.51.209.in-addr.arpa name = ea.c5.33.static.xlhost.com.
31.204.150.10           10.150.204.31.in-addr.arpa  name = hosted-by-i3d.net.
209.51.197.218          218.197.51.209.in-addr.arpa name = da.c5.33.static.xlhost.com.
207.46.13.25            25.13.46.207.in-addr.arpa   name = msnbot-207-46-13-25.search.msn.com.
200.105.189.165         165.189.105.200.in-addr.arpa    name = static-200-105-189-165.acelerate.net.
198.62.109.139          139.109.62.198.in-addr.arpa name = jangan.sebok.share.
78.187.209.209          209.209.187.78.in-addr.arpa name = 78.187.209.209.static.ttnet.com.tr.
197.33.99.78            78.99.33.197.in-addr.arpa   name = host-197.33.99.78.tedata.net.
197.157.0.45            ** server can't find 45.0.157.197.in-addr.arpa.: NXDOMAIN
180.76.15.6             6.15.76.180.in-addr.arpa    name = baiduspider-180-76-15-6.crawl.baidu.com.
176.10.104.243          243.104.10.176.in-addr.arpa name = tor2e1.privacyfoundation.ch.
174.129.237.157         157.237.129.174.in-addr.arpa    name = ec2-174-129-237-157.compute-1.amazonaws.com.
174.102.192.129         129.192.102.174.in-addr.arpa    name = cpe-174-102-192-129.wi.res.rr.com.
```

As an example, for `nslookup 97.33.99.78` result

```
97.33.99.78         78.99.33.197.in-addr.arpa   name = host-197.33.99.78.tedata.net.
```

I want to extract `tedata.net` domain base.

But some domain base have 3 or 4 components: `wi.res.rr.com` and `static.ttnet.com.tr`

Also for `XLHOST`, I am not sure to chose `static.xlhost.com` or `xlhost.com` for search repeating pattern.

```
209.190.54.154          154.54.190.209.in-addr.arpa name = 9a.36.be.static.xlhost.com.
209.51.199.34           34.199.51.209.in-addr.arpa  name = 22.c7.33.static.xlhost.com.
209.51.197.234          234.197.51.209.in-addr.arpa name = ea.c5.33.static.xlhost.com.
```

What do you recommend to detect abusive IPs that generate from specific server?

Comment: to get "final" domain name : `... | awk -F. '{printf "%s.%s\n",$(NF-2),$(NF-1)}'  `

Comment: @Archemar, looks good but fails to grab if domain contains one more field. For example: `nslookup 78.189.102.236 | grep name | awk -F. '{printf "%s.%s\n",$(NF-2),$(NF-1)}'` just prints `com.tr`

Answer (score 1):

The IP-address that you used for the lookup is what matters for blocking.  The hostname can have (as far as you are concerned) arbitrary names that may imply addresses, but to the extent that those names mean something, they may only mean something on that host's *local* network.

A given server may be only a *gateway* server, and (relatively) innocent.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, but I am getting thousands of requests from xlhost.com. Should not searching patterns help detect the abusive servers, even if the results may not be reliable? What do you recommend for such kind of cases?

Comment: You *might* get some repeatable patterns, but what I've seen for this sort of case is that large providers has many dynamic addresses, and that they can change without a discernible pattern.